# Refreshing fullcalendar view on day change

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Assuming a fullcalendar-based application running over midnight, what would be the recommended way to auto-refresh the view in order to have fc-today class properly applied to the new day.

Just calling 'today' doesn't have an effect if the current view's date ranges are not changing. My current hack is to do something like this after midnight:

```
calendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', '2000-01-01');
calendar.fullCalendar('today');
```

Is there a better/easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry that this is 5 years late, but just ran into this same issue and got the solution from a coworker. You can add a key prop to your FullCalendar call and set that to the current date. This will force it to unmount and remount the component when the date changes. This is using a TypeScript React implementation of FullCalendar.

```
getCurrentDay() {
return moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY')
}

<FullCalendar
key={this.getCurrentDay()}
...
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

1. Store a cookie/session variable setting the date/default view you want on next refresh.
2. Refresh the page (browser refresh)
3. Retreive #1 and set the defaults in the fullCalendar(..) call.

Another option would be to try fullCalendar's reload event call and see if that fully redraws the table?

Comment: Thanks, but I would prefer not reloading the full page to avoid handling state restore for any other components that may be there beside the calendar.

Comment: Then simply reload fullCalendar by call it an all options again. Or see if calling the reload events does what you need